# Maxima add current loop iteration to filename

Tags: output, maxima, wxmaxima

I have code similar to the one below, where a function with a parameter depending on the loop iteration is plotted after every iteration. I would like to save the plot with the name trigplot_i.ps where i is the iteration number, but don't know how.

I have tried trigplot_"i".ps but didn't work, and have not been able to find how to cast i to a string either.

I'm a beginner so any help is very welcome.

```
f(x) := sin(x);
g(x) := cos(x);
for i:1 thru 10 do
    (plot2d([i*f(x), i*g(x)], [x,-5,5],[legend,"sin(x)","cos(x)"],
    [xlabel,"x"],[ylabel,"y"],
    [ps_file,"./trigplot_i.ps"],
    [gnuplot_preamble,"set key box spacing 1.3 top right"])
);
```

code after edits gives an error:

```
f(x) := sin(x);
g(x) := cos(x);
for i:1 thru 10
    do block([myfile],
        myfile: sconcat("./trigplot_", i, ".ps"),
        printf (true, "iteration ~d, myfile = ~a~%", myfile),
        plot2d([i*f(x), i*g(x)], [x,-5,5],[legend,"sin(x)","cos(x)"],
        [xlabel,"x"],[ylabel,"y"],
        [ps_file, myfile],
        [gnuplot_preamble,"set key box spacing 1.3 top right"])
);
```

error:
"declare: argument must be a symbol; found "./trigplot_1.ps
-- an error.
To debug this try: debugmode(true);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. To construct a file name, try this: `sconcat("./trigplot_", i, ".ps")` or also you can try: `printf(false, "./trigplot_~d.ps", i)`. My advice is to make that a separate step in the loop, and then you can use it in the call to `plot2d`, e.g.:

```
for i:1 thru 10
  do block ([myfile],
            myfile: sconcat("./trigplot_", i, ".ps"),
            printf (true, "iteration ~d, myfile = ~a~%", i, myfile),
            plot2d (<stuff goes here>, [ps_file, myfile], <more stuff>));
```

EDIT: Fixed a bug in `printf` (omitted argument `i`).

Comment: Thanks! After the edits I still get an error "declare: argument must be a symbol; found "./trigplot_1.ps"
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);". I posted the edited code in my post.

Comment: Oh, sorry, there was a bug in `printf`. I've updated the code.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you! I have low rep so my votes don't show, but I marked the answer as accepted and upvoted it too.